# How to create Flutter Custom App Bar Floating Style with Radius Corners?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to customize the App bar like below, with rounded style and it floats on top of all other widgets:
[image: screenshot of intended custom App bar]

Its similar to Google Map app. What would be the best way to achieve this customization?

Thanks for any advice or guides to approach this...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget to display a widget on top of another widget (page content in your example). So use [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) to place search / app bar on top of main app content and customize as your needs.

You can check [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liEGSeD3Zt8) to learn more about Stack widget.

Here's sample code, you can place inside `Scaffold`.

```dart
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    // this will be filled entire screen
    Positioned.fill(child: Image.network('https://i.imgur.com/SJGDZUp.png')),

    // this will be placed top of the screen with 15 points distance
    Positioned(
      top: 15,
      left: 15,
      right: 15,
      // using SafeArea to avoid device frames (for example notch in iPhones)
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          child: Text('Search...', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

*DISCLAIMER: I haven't tested the code, so, it may contain syntax issues or typos*

Comment: Great the Stacking part seems straightforward.

Now is there any easy way to customize the shape of the App bar or that’s something more complex?

Thanks for any advice or guides to fully customize the app bar design...

Comment: TLDR: Use `Container` instead of `AppBar`.

@Effie, you can use Container instead of AppBar and customize it like I did. AppBar is not that customizable widget like container. Because flutter is based on widgets not native components. So putting things in wrong place is possible and it will not break something (I'm not sure but you might want to change system status bar color too, google to learn more). So you can place other widgets to container. Actually AppBar itself is created using other widgets like Row, Column, Container and so on.